# Calling getChildAt() method of ListView after setting Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, nullpointerexception

I am trying to run `ListView.getChildAt()` method after I called `setAdapter()` of ListView but it gives me `NullPointerException`. It seems setting adapter doesn't cause the child views to be created. As the method below tells, I am trying to get the child view so that I can change its background color. How can I fix this problem?

```
private void showAnswers(int questionLocation)
{
    List<Answer> answers = getAnswersByQuestionLocation(questionLocation);

    ArrayAdapter<String> answerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1);

    for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++)
    {
        answerAdapter.add(mOptionLetters[i] +". "+ answers.get(i).getAnswerText());
    }

    mAnswerList.setAdapter(answerAdapter);

    if (mAnswerLocationByQuestionLocation.indexOfKey(questionLocation) > -1)
    {
        Log.v("Child Count",String.valueOf(mAnswerList.getChildCount()));

            //mAnswerList.getChildAt(
            //       mAnswerLocationByQuestionLocation.get(questionLocation))
            //      .setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if is all your need is to change the background, 
here how it works:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> answerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View v =super.getView(position, convertView, parent);;
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            return v;
        }

    };
```

---

Because you are running on UI thread, the listView will need enough time to create views in next loop in the thread, but you can't guess when.
so the best way is to override `getView` in the adapter, since the adapter feeds the listView with childs :)

---

```
class MyModel {

           public MyMode(String txt){
             this.txt = txt
            }

        public String txt;
        public boolean isSelected;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return txt;
        }
    }
```

---

```
ArrayAdapter<MyModel> answerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyModel>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View v =super.getView(position, convertView, parent);;
        MyModel  model = getItem(position);
        if(model.isSelected){
           v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);} 
         else{
           v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);}
        return v;
    }

};
```

---

```
answerAdapter.add(new MyModel(mOptionLetters[i] +". "+ answers.get(i).getAnswerText()));
```

---

```
if (mAnswerLocationByQuestionLocation.indexOfKey(questionLocation) > -1)
    {
        MyModel model = (MyModel)mAnswerList.getItemAtPosition(questionLocation);
    model.isSelected= true;
    answerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

anyway you need to read this tutorial about ListViews and Adapters 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Nope. I am changing background when someone click on either next or previous buttons on the navigation page so that the selected answer can be preserved and displayed to the user.

Comment: So, you must use a `Model` having a `flag` that this answer was selected, then notify the adapter to recreate the views.

Comment: refresh the answer :)

Comment: I guess you also need to set TextView text field in getView method.

Comment: yes, if you are using `BaseAdapter`, but in your case the `ArrayAdapter` will inflate the Views in `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1` for you

Comment: after you add all answers to `answerAdapter` you need to call `answerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: I have one more question for you. Instead of changing background color, I want it to be like `v.setSelected(true)` so that when they choose another option, the pre-selected one becomes white again. But unfortunately `v.setSelected(true)` does not do the job here? What else I can use or how can I make it work?

Comment: no, even you do this, you need to reset the `isSelected` value for another models